# Unity3d grid is not displayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010, game-engine

I created a project in unity 3d and the coordinate grid does not work for me, I turned it on, changed the visibility of this grid, changed coordinates, changed screens (layout) from tall to width and back, but nothing helps, how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Is [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/grid-in-scene-view-gone-solved.60711/) the same problem as yours? Possible solution by SundownStudio: "Just close the scene tab, then open it again from 'Window -> General'."

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a default 1m cube at the origin, Frame it by pressing F, and try all the steps you have before again, My guess is your camera is either zoomed in or out too much, or pointing away from the grid